# How to retrieve internal Id from a transformed record in NetSuite (SuiteScript)

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I am transforming a sales order to an invoice record in SuiteScript 2.1

```
            let soIID = 1 //just for the sake of the question, this will come from getInputData on a M/R
            let invoiceRecord = record.transform({
                fromType: 'salesorder',
                fromId: soIID,
                toType: 'invoice',
            });

            invoiceRecord.setValue('trandate', new Date(soDate.trandate));
            invoiceRecord.save();

            let invoiceId = invoiceRecord.getValue('id');               //Problem here
            let invoiceId2 = invoiceRecord.getValue({fieldId: 'id'});   //Problem here
```

My issue is that I cannot retrieve the invoiceId from the transformed record even after a .save() event. I know that both invoiceId and invoiceId2 would work if I first did a record.load() but I still have the problem of not knowing the ID of the invoice record.

When I log the invoiceRecord object the ID isn't included.

How do I retrieve the ID from the newly created object?

Answer (score 1):

`Record.save()` returns the internal ID of the record that was created so you don't have to retrieve it using `getValue`.

```
const invoiceId = invoiceRecord.save();
```